# Will plywood installed over Thermo-Ply cause moisture problems?

Tags: exterior, sheathing

Having the stucco removed and HardiePank fibercement siding installed.  The house has overlapped [Thermo-Ply](https://www.buildwithbmc.com/bmc/Lumber-Boards/Panels-Sheathings/Sheathing/Thermo-Ply-Sheathing-Structural-Grade-Red-R18/p/TP18483410R#:%7E:text=Thermo%2Dply%C2%AE%20Structural%20Sheathing,alternative%20to%20wood%20structural%20panels.&text=With%20grades%20and%20options%20to,%2Din%2Dclass%20air%20barrier.) as the sheathing, and the contractor wants to put plywood over the thermo-ply.  Should I be concerned about moisture getting trapped between plywood and the Thermo-Ply?

Comment: Welcome. What's the reasoning for the additional sheathing?

Comment: Also, one could assume that a new waterproof membrane would be installed under the siding. That's maybe more of a concern.